# How to set Required area in form with google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I make a form with Google script

but I don't know how to make it's field to be REQUIRED

following is my script but my gbchk(form) didn't work

The script will add a line in my excel in my google dive

but even there is no data in the form

How to make a required area in google script?

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}
function uploadFiles(form) {
  try {
    
    var folderName = "Upload";
    var sheetName = "ulist";
    var folder;
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
    
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
    }
    //handling uploading file
    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by "+ form.myName);    
    
    var fileUrl = file.getUrl();
    
    
    var FileIterator = DriveApp.getFilesByName(sheetName);
    var sheetApp = "";
    while (FileIterator.hasNext())
    {
      var sheetFile = FileIterator.next();
      if (sheetFile.getName() == sheetName)
      {
        
        sheetApp = SpreadsheetApp.open(sheetFile);
      }    
    }
   
    if(sheetApp == "")
    {
      sheetApp = SpreadsheetApp.create(sheetName);
    }
    
    var sheet = sheetApp.getSheets()[0];
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    
          
    var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 2, 1, 1).setValues([[lastRow+1,form.myName]]);
   
    return "Upload Success!"
    
  } catch (error) {
    
    return "Upload fail because:"+error.toString();
  }
  
}
function gbchk(form)                
{             
  if (form.myName.value == "")                
  {                
    alert("Enter your name!!");                
    form.myName.focus();                
    return (false);                
  }    
  return (true);                
}
```

Comment: You could have the function not submit the data if the required field is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put a `required` tag on the html form input. The docs for this can be found here:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation#The_required_attribute

example:

```
<form>
  <label for="choose">Would you prefer a banana or cherry?</label>
  <input id="choose" name="i_like" pattern="banana|cherry" required>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a solution too.

Putting a `required` tag on the input fields would work. But the user can simply remove it throught the dev tools.

A slightly better approach is to set the `required` tags by JS. Users can still get around it, but this time they need to modify the JS itself.